# How can i reproduce "java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection" error on local?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, datasource, oracle12c

I am having this problem on Testing and Production Env. When after the DB connection is gone for sometime, after the db is up the application logs shows it is running fine but in actual the batch jobs are not running anymore and i have to restart the server.

So to resolve that, i have to reproduce the issue on local.
Can anybody tell me how to reproduce this exception on local.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.needLine(PhysicalConnection.java:4216) ~[ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.closeOrCache(OracleStatement.java:1431) ~[ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.close(OracleStatement.java:1410) ~[ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.close(OracleStatementWrapper.java:102) ~[ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.close(NewProxyStatement.java:178) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53) [mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar:0.2.11]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester.activeCheckConnection(DefaultConnectionTester.java:325) [c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:510) [c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.testPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:464) [c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.refurbishIdleResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:436) [c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:2211) [c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
```

I'm using `spring-batch`, `oracle 12c`.
`c3P0 datasource` is used to make connection with the db.

Comment: Have you tried to stop (and then restart) your local DB server while the job is running?

Comment: How long is your connection being held open for and is there a firewall between your app and the db server?  Firewalls typically do not like long held connections and need rules to prevent them from being shut.